# How to set a number of loops for a chrome javascript snippet?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I found this great script to let me unfollow all of my followers that I've accumulated over the years. I do get maxed out by Twitter and would love to modify the script to only loop 100 times before stopping.

```
i=0;   
 setInterval(function(){t=$(".js-follow-btn").eq(i);  
 if(!t[0])window.scrollTo(0,$(document).height());  
 else t.trigger("click")  
 i++;},1000)
```

Comment: By saying "I woud love to modify the script" without any effort on your part, you are basically asking "can someone write this for me?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `clearInterval()` function.

Example with your code:

```
i=0;   
var interval = setInterval(function(){ //assign the interval to variable so you can later clear it. :)
    if (i >= 99) clearInterval(interval); //If you passed the number of tries required, clear the interval. Since you start from 0, on 100th try i will be 99).
    t=$(".js-follow-btn").eq(i);  
    if(!t[0])window.scrollTo(0,$(document).height());  
    else t.trigger("click");
    i++;
},1000)
```

Its using the i counter you already had implemented.